# Where does Msys put openssl runtime libs?

Tags: dll, rust, openssl, msys2

I'm trying to build some lib for android and that lib uses `hyper-native-tls`.

To build it I need to specify `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR`.

I used `Msys2` to install `openssl` and managed to find the include directory which is `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`.

Now I can't find `OPENSSL_LIB_DIR` which as said  [here](https://docs.rs/crate/openssl/0.10.7/source/README.md).

> If specified, a directory that will be used to find
> OpenSSL libraries.

I tried to put many directories but all of them fail. Where can I find the specified dir or what's the right dir w.r.t. `Msys2` for the dlls?

---

**The Error says**

```
 --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'OpenSSL libdir at `C:\msys64\usr\lib\openssl\` does not contain the required files to either statically or dynamically link OpenSSL', C:\Users\Me\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\openssl-sys-0.9.61\build/main.rs:332:13
```

Comment: If you're building for Android, then you need the OpenSSL libs for Android, but MSys will only have OpenSSL for your PC, so even if you put the right path (which I assume is `c:\msys64\mingw64\lib`), it won't work because the OpenSSL it finds will not target Android.

Comment: Note that `native-tls` has a `vendored` feature where it builds its own version of OpenSSL instead of attempting to use an external one. This might work for you.

Comment: @Jmb thank u. your comments helped me. you may post an answer.